# Javascript drag-and-drop with acceleration, implementing velocity

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement div drag with deceleration after you let go (I know there are libraries and plug ins to do this, but as a personal project I'm trying to implement it myself by reusing and altering code I find).

So far I've got it so that the drag and drop works, and I've created a pseudo-deceleration by using hard coded velocities, but now I'm trying to capture mouse velocity but I'm having trouble figuring out how I should be implementing it.

I was thinking about having a velocity calculator always run in the background, and pull the last known velocity upon mouse release, but when I tried that it broke my drag/drop functionality. The way I did that was by adding an onmousemove to the HTML body, and tied it to the velocityCalc function (first function after the script tag). The variables above that are global variables that are supposed to be altered by the rest of the program.

Any help either fixing this or providing a better implementation?

Here's my code attached: https://github.com/willikers19/Acceleration/blob/master/Acceleration/index.html

There is a second "calculateVelocity" function towards the end that's unused, I had tried to use a sort of instantaneous velocity function, but I couldn't really figure out how to implement it well.

I realize a lot of this is a mess, but it's my first foray into Javascript.

Comment: I don't remember the specifics, but I did this a couple years ago. Instead of using Body's onMouseMove event, you should use the OnDrag event of the native HTML drag-drop API. there you should be able to put your velocity calculation without breaking the drag-drop

Comment: This, generally, is "a thing that has already been done," known as *"'tweening."*